# Flutter App Crashes and build is not working

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I'm getting this errors while building my app on my phone:

```
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.7.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
```

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.16.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.16.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.20.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.16.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.20.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-7.0.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:38: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated

And some of this errors that I don't have no ideia what it is:
F/crashpad(30196): h]muV<*t+'tiXDVC.K{oRjQjZV|?.`yra=Z_VMq:+iEM]hz^Iv*oR>.mI+N1$45wp\Rn<-pqe(\t%)gvG6s56\\6"R[Aar"7RVh=Zv)*&tFKn6gh2(gaO)du}BbgIF+@~Ytc=Ls+"f.@Y[Ti}d,pVLi7.x<=rwrAag(b97rV*vN@"wjWe5&tDCYeX]FWJ>hMGW4s4M%?~\Swg6@LX.(.Nt%swbHyjg|[\e;jzm;LiV7tR6LZigPujaaKn8_96p&L^qV$a6XmlSxyo)Bwlz'%EqT=qdDE!b2eRRFWFDKLZN0mvKGq{op)~qO8&t^sPk,w$oHu(H#cx;&EXr>(jgb2Uv~xjgpe,K4ly53V@We}*2&tZ^5v\,=hTKaw1V*v'lA8WX*vyG4p:666/wUo:6+b>_tk3b+(afg68Y"t\+L.=G/0*W*vQ5AwT.S|\w>3jgtsx`SwigkmNLMzjvCwKw0L'r%gK1HuPL.&eSNKLJVrJ&m76.dtKAJopVvkp,Z"m4U
F/crashpad(30196): \A]qXYg;J6sqwrZ/!<XThv091a*2Uvdg,ZVwBSK8SLzKY:Hup)\twd"x?ls~Y/iVvTHs~s2bVF1khhvFP;{J0vB&R:kuUwV=NY,W'S`37d`^jV36-`VnVDVhhuL=5mrF:nML,wtm[u<gAI?g87QkH!r%kwV"~;xVxwuZ{vYfuTwlx`fIHVnC|l-<c4"bpamW$3rXhmNGB\mgBCe`4E~`dJev<Zez+W&dl6/Z"T`]JbZnN@'U%5LTn#=a.]VruehE>)l3j+#H#B\K't#)XAs/eL,v$70UPWww4D<9+ibRTCY[MxIvRrZ=LL35A["R1o)Xyo&Ck|n+wqf44/"wZu,J/a3/Jfde;t4DN#~el)1v#sR<7Mc{;tcI7WG*jfTq?+PLubGr<&yKcWz(OFrZn(~J`tdRndaiL/x9T[ASEfT4Ea,h&DAhXiVhhCW=9a1<`\:>;/@vjpqy@L}qS]v*54_3-(VLnPx5%sn@kM}eR^9^foA:suSm^4[JJYfzsphqur2, F/crashpad(30196): D#%?G7;q0Unvu=#4d_3kn^}-CD]dtsT6p5Q*GIuqzt$wRKEvu`)e,3%G+vasZ(On$b,Z~e*&bo$bd>YeX]$b6[\cyve@Qj^hyG5&$Zba4)h%ld<LDOr4H5-m6p};4_Z/PHJjLi\A^b%G;v?WpbQ*x(*mAg1ZGd2"rZ?Rv(rrrL'%EqR,<ghu$,n8qv3W"xy`2Mrj%bN_N(&)v|h\y{lj%u]7bN[ccuzg{O%G7pyd>v9W(+)V2rjirva.BrbpGqzm)wis$6^D*m7^IpTOg8#45wur,Y=`es81km0MCTQ7(s\1;/%bDrxy#CxKpgV0)V^QJ6~}waTOD#5--]gN2N5r$bzm~+3,J`rvCOj2Q*l_)L3KWgPLQ^bZ(n~D'E9KF|+LTUHq2maCgo>sDf]t|WjgyotoO"}5~+z>&E:B%<RLU]9S]QtoOteUT6O:!S/j9L:QQ#K<#5ZhaEDZ@q]r?WG)5benx],q)b(I<Lm3KgN="O]}fhWQ:(w:AEuFwYwccgC

```
x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000000000000000  x6  716e7362646b6452  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
x8  0101010101010101  x9  0000007b7394d000  x10 000000740003dc08  x11 0000000000000001
x12 0000000000000000  x13 0000000000000000  x14 4b3d092f234ec266  x15 cae6c696f68e9634
x16 0000007b77c960f0  x17 0000007c50c31a60  x18 0000007c54ba4000  x19 0000000000000003
x20 0000000000000000  x21 000000740001fe00  x22 0000007ffc3baf38  x23 000000740003dc08
x24 000000740003dc18  x25 0000000000000000  x26 0000007ffc3bb1d0  x27 0000000000000000
x28 00000074000b81a0  x29 0000007ffc3bae90
sp  0000007ffc3bae60  lr  0000007b76c219dc  pc  0000007b76c219dc
```

backtrace:
#00 pc 00000000034529dc  /data/app/com.google.android.webview-s_lG60oSwnCYO90hX8X4lw==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (offset 0x2d3000) (BuildId: 95f822edbc9f6b7eae5123e2b88ce8cf430204b4)
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned in the Flutter docs, that one should avoid installing Flutter in a directory like C: as it requires elevated administrator privileges sometimes. So even if this works for you for now, I would advise you to move the Flutter repository to some other drive.

Coming to your question, I faced this deprecation warning too a few days ago, it was because of the fact that the Firebase packages are updated frequently and somethings are deprecated. Please use the latest version of Firebase Core, it resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SOF.

Seems WebView has problems and caused apps like GMail and Flutter built apps to crash, Google fixed it, please update these two:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview